# Create a dataframe from dictionary and both key and value are rows

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a dictionary where keys are patient ids, and values are same for all keys: [1, 2, 3], indicating each patient will visit the clinic 3 times. How can I convert it to a dataframe where both the keys and the values are rows?

Dictionary:

```
patients = ['Patient01', 'patient02', 'patient03']
visits = [1,2,3]
dictionary = {k:visits for k in patients}
```

output:

```
{'Patient01': [1, 2, 3],
 'patient02': [1, 2, 3],
 'patient03': [1, 2, 3]}
```

I tried

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dictionary, orient = 'index')
```

but the output is

```
            0   1   2
patient02   1   2   3
patient03   1   2   3
patient01   1   2   3
```

and what I want is like this:

```
          visit_num
patient01  1
patient01  2
patient01  3
patient02  1
patient02  2
patient02  3
patient03  1
patient03  2
patient03  3
```

Comment: There you have it.  Lots of answers to choose from. :)  #SOreadytohelp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
data = [[patient, visit_num]
        for patient, visits in dictionary.items()
        for visit_num in visits]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['patient', 'visit_num']).set_index('patient')
```

Answer (score 7):

Use [`pd.stack()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) on the dataframe you created:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dictionary, orient = 'index')

new_df = df.stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True).to_frame(name='visit_num')

>>> new_df
           visit num
Patient01          1
Patient01          2
Patient01          3
patient02          1
patient02          2
patient02          3
patient03          1
patient03          2
patient03          3
```

**Note of explanation**:

`df.stack` does most of the work here, taking your original `df`

```
           0  1  2
Patient01  1  2  3
patient02  1  2  3
patient03  1  2  3
```

and turns it into the following multi-indexed `pandas.Series`:

```
Patient01  0    1
           1    2
           2    3
patient02  0    1
           1    2
           2    3
patient03  0    1
           1    2
           2    3
```

The rest of the line (`.reset_index()` and `.to_frame()`) is simply there to get it into a nice dataframe format.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html#pandas-melt):

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dictionary, orient = 'index')
df.reset_index()\
  .melt('index',value_name='visit_num')\
  .drop('variable', axis=1)\
  .sort_values('index') #if you wish to get your order
```

Output:

```
       index  visit_num
1  Patient01          1
4  Patient01          2
7  Patient01          3
2  patient02          1
5  patient02          2
8  patient02          3
0  patient03          1
3  patient03          2
6  patient03          3
```

Answer (score 4):

Straight from a comprehension

```
pd.Series(
    *zip(*((v, k) for k, c in dictionary.items() for v in c))
).to_frame('visit_num')

           visit_num
Patient01          1
Patient01          2
Patient01          3
patient02          1
patient02          2
patient02          3
patient03          1
patient03          2
patient03          3
```

Comment: this gets a +1 for originality

Answer (score 2):

You can use `itertools.product` to simply your problem, followed by `pd.DataFrame.set_index`.

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import product

patients = ['Patient01', 'patient02', 'patient03']
visits = [1, 2, 3]

df = pd.DataFrame(list(product(patients, visits)), columns=['patients', 'visit_num'])\
       .set_index('patients')
```

Comment: doesn't this assume that all of the patients had the same number of visits?

Comment: @pault. Precisely. As per the question: "values are same for all keys"

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try with `numpy`

```
pd.DataFrame({'visit_num':np.hstack(list(dictionary.values()))},index=np.repeat(list(dictionary.keys()),len(dictionary)))
Out[76]: 
           visit_num
Patient01          1
Patient01          2
Patient01          3
patient02          1
patient02          2
patient02          3
patient03          1
patient03          2
patient03          3
```