# openpyxl : Update multiple columns & rows from dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, openpyxl

I have a nested Dictionary

```
aDictionary = {'Asset': {'Name': 'Max', 'Age': 28, 'Job': 'Nil'}, 'Parameter': {'Marks': 60, 'Height': 177, 'Weight': 76}}
```

I want to update the values in an excel as follows

```
|Asset    |Name  |Max|
|Asset    |Age   |28 |
|Asset    |Job   |Nil|
|Parameter|Marks |60 |
|Parameter|Height|177|
|Parameter|Weight|76 |
```

I tried something like this, but result is not what I was expecting. Am pretty new to openpyxl. I can't seem to wrap my head around it.

```
from openpyxl import *

workbook=load_workbook('Empty.xlsx')
    worksheet= workbook['Sheet1']
    
    for m in range(1,7):
        for i in aDictionary:
            worksheet["A"+str(m)].value=i
            for j, k in aDictionary[i].items():
                worksheet["B"+str(m)].value=j
                worksheet["C"+str(m)].value=k
    workbook.save('Empty.xlsx')
```

Comment: What you need to do is expand the dictionaries into lists. Do this first in Python before you try and add the values to the worksheet. Once that works, you can just use `ws.append()`

Comment: Will this expanding it to 2 different list affect performance if more data is involved?

Comment: Worry about performance after you have things working. If you do things properly I don't think it will matter.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to convert the Dictionary to a DataFrame and stack it the way you indicated, rearrange the columns and then load it into Excel. I've used `pandas to_excel` as it is a single line of code. But, you can use `load_workbook()` as well...
Stacking part was borrowed from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49779515/create-a-dataframe-from-dictionary-and-both-key-and-value-are-rows)

**Code**

```
aDictionary = {'Asset': {'Name': 'Max', 'Age': 28, 'Job': 'Nil'}, 'Parameter': {'Marks': 60, 'Height': 177, 'Weight': 76}}

df = pd.DataFrame(aDictionary) # Convert to dataframe
df = df.stack().reset_index()  # Stack

# Rearrange columns to the way you want it
cols = df.columns.tolist()     
cols = list(df.columns.values)
cols[0], cols[1] = cols[1], cols[0]
df = df[cols]

#Write to Excel
df.to_excel('Empty.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False, header=None)
```

**Output in Excel**

[image]